# Cannot set `app:layout_behavior` on fragment tag

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, android-appbarlayout

I have a simple fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the `SampleFragment2.kt` I simply inflate the above layout.

I include it below my `AppBarLayout` and add the `app:layout_behaviour` tag to it:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <!-- ... -->
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/somefragment"
        android:name="com.company.sample.SampleFragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />
```

And this gives me runtime error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams`

If I omit the `fragment` tag and simply put the `LinearLayout` from the fragment below the `AppBarLayout` and add the `app:layout_behavior` tag there, it works just fine.

How can I achieve the same behavior when using a `fragment` tag?

Comment: I would guess that it's actually the `app:layout_anchor="@id/tabLayout"` that's causing the issue. Is `tabLayout` inside your `<AppBarLayout>`?

Comment: @MikeM. yes, tablayout is inside. the anchor attributes were exactly the problem. I removed the anchor stuff and now it works just fine! I would have never thought of that. Thank you, you saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeM. pointed out in his comment, `app:layout_anchor="@id/tabLayout"` was the problem. I removed all anchor attributes and it worked.